# Step Complexity of thrust sort and thrust unique by key

Tags: gpu, thrust

I was just wondering what is the step complexity of the `thrust::sort` function and what are work and step complexity of the `thrust::unique_by_key` function.

Based on my knowledge, I think the work complexity of sorting is O(N log N). But I have no idea what it is for the `unique_by_key` operation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of sort in Thrust.  There is a radix sort and a comparison sort.  For radix sort, the work complexity is O(kN), where N is the number of keys and k is the key length.  For comparison sort, the work complexity is O(N log N), as you mentioned.

`unique_by_key` is a stream compaction operation, which means that work complexity is O(N).